# ONNX Operators for Regex Replacements

Tags: python, string, scikit-learn, onnx

***QUESTION:** How can I use ONNX operators to do string replacements with regular expressions?*

I am trying to export a [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) machine learning pipeline to the [Open Neural Network Exchange (ONNX)](https://onnx.ai/) format. The pipeline takes text as input. Many of the steps that are included in the pipeline are nicely included in the standard, like a TfIdfVectorizer and a TruncatedSVD transformer. However, the first pipeline step is a custom transformer which makes a set of changes to the input text through the exploitation of regular expressions.

When adding a custom transformer, the [scikitlearn-onnx docs suggest that a custom shape and converter function should be written](http://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/auto_tutorial/plot_icustom_converter.html). The converter function in particular must be written by combining a set of [predefined operators](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md) that exist within the ONNX standard. However, from what I can tell, it is not possible to do even basic string manipulation with the operators that exist.

One of the regular expression powered replacements that I want to make is a unit conversion, for example:

```
12m -> 12 meters
```

With Python's `re` package this is trivial:

```py
import re

my_string = "The Empire State Building is 443m tall."

meters_pattern = re.compile("(?<=[0-9])m ")
my_transformed_string = re.sub(meters_pattern, " meters ", my_string)

>>> print(my_transformed_string)
The Empire State Building is 443 meters tall.
```

However, I cannot conceive of a way to do this with the available ONNX operators. Here's what I've thought to try:

1. Use a regular expression opererator in a similar manner to the Python example above.

**Problem:** ONNX does not have a regex operator.

2. Evaluate the input string sequentially, one character at a time. If an "m" follows a digit, change the string as described above.

**Problem:** This approach requires a comparison of strings: does "this character in the string" equal "m"? However, the existing [`OnnxEqual`](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#Equal) operator does not support string comparison.

3. Translate the input string, character by character, to it's ASCII decimal equivalent and then perform step 2.

**Problem:** ONNX does not have a translate-like operator (like [GNU `tr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html)) for strings. ONNX also does not support casting non-strictly numeric strings with [`OnnxCast`](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#Cast).

4. Use the [`OnnxUnique`](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#Unique) operator and it's `inverse_indicies` property to translate the input string to something approximating each character's ASCII decimal value.

**Problem:** This requires prepending a key string ``` \t\n\r !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_``abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ``` to the beginning of the input string (so that the numerical values found by `OnnxUnique`'s `inverse_indicies` property have a consistent definition) and splitting the input string into a sequence of tensors of one character each. Unfortunately, [`OnnxSplit`](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#Split) errors when trying to split a string tensor (see code example below), and [`OnnxSequenceInsert`](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#SequenceInsert) does not append strings into a single element tensor, just a sequence of single element tensors into a single tensor with multiple elements.

```py
import re
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from skl2onnx import to_onnx, update_registered_converter
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import StringTensorType
from skl2onnx.algebra.onnx_ops import OnnxSplit, OnnxConstant
from onnxruntime import InferenceSession

class MyTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return re.sub("(?<=[0-9])m ", " meters ", X)

def shape_function(operator):
    input = StringTensorType([1])
    output = StringTensorType([None, 1])
    operator.inputs[0].type = input
    operator.outputs[0].type = output

def converter_function(scope, operator, container):
    op = operator.raw_operator
    opv = container.target_opset
    out = operator.outputs

    X = operator.inputs[0]

    one_tensor = OnnxConstant(value_int=1, op_version=opv)
    string_tensor = OnnxConstant(value_strings=["ab"], op_version=opv)
    string_split_tensor = OnnxSplit(string_tensor, one_tensor, op_version=opv, output_names=out[:1])

    string_split_tensor.add_to(scope, container)

update_registered_converter(MyTransformer, "MyTransformer", shape_function, converter_function)
my_transformer = MyTransformer()
onnx_model = to_onnx(my_transformer, initial_types=[["X", StringTensorType([None, 1])]])

test_string = "The Empire State Building is 443m tall."
sess = InferenceSession(onnx_model.SerializeToString())
output = sess.run(None, {"X": np.array([test_string])})
```

Yields:

```py
2022-08-16 12:35:46.235861185 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:106 MergeShapeInfo] Error merging shape info for output. 'variable' source:{1} target:{,1}. Falling back to lenient
merge.
2022-08-16 12:35:46.237767860 [E:onnxruntime:, inference_session.cc:1530 operator()] Exception during initialization: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/optimizer/optimizer_execution_frame.cc:75 onnxruntime::OptimizerExecutionFrame::Info::Info(const std::vector<const onnxruntime::Node*>&, const InitializedTensorSet&, const onnxruntime::Path&,
const onnxruntime::IExecutionProvider&, const std::function<bool(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>&) [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : string tensor can not use pre-allocated buffer
```

How is one to properly manipulate strings with the available ONNX operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the ONNX developers this question, and as of August 2022, it simply is not possible to perform REGEX replacements with ONNX operators. See the full thread here: https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/4450